# Display one specific row from an array of data

Tags: reactjs

In the official documentation in the section lists and keys, I found a code to practice where I can get an array of all data, but I can't get an specific row from this array.

```
  function Blog(props) {
  const sidebar = (
    <ul>
      {props.posts.map((post) =>
        <li key={post.id}>
          {post.title}
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
  const content = props.posts.map((post) =>
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.title}</h3>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {sidebar}
      <hr />
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

const posts = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Hello World', content: 'Welcome to learning React!'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Installation', content: 'You can install React from npm.'}
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Blog posts={posts} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I was trying with adding to the key the array of of the specific id

```
<div key={post.id && post[0]}>
```

...or adding a for loop that doesn't work for me neither.

I would like to get only the entire id: 1

I guess this is easier than that unless I have to use some state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the index of that poarticular post, you can reference it directly

```
const post = props.post[index];

// if index= 1
const post = props.post[1];
```

When you are displaying a single item, you don't need key as it is required when displaying a list of items. This is how you'd display post

```
<div>
  <h3>{post.title}</h3>
  <p>{post.content}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work.  It says post is already been used,or content is declared and never used or directly give me and error.  I'm trying to put inside the function and outside and nothing  Thanks

Comment: ok. I got it. Outside the function after the data and then you declare directly in the div because you have been past already the props. Thanks mate

Comment: Glad! You can accept the answer if it worked for you @Pascual